# How do I set a class variable in this scenario

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Here is some code:

```
class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=2, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class MyDynamicMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyMplCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.line, = self.axes.plot([],[],color='b')
        self.axes.set_title(self.title)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("Time")
        self.axes.ticklabel_format(style='plain',useOffset = False)

    def update_figure(self,voltage):    
        self.line.set_data(np.linspace(0,len(voltage)-1,num = len(voltage)), voltage) 
        self.axes.relim()
        self.axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
        self.draw()


class Monitor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ac_1_graph = MyDynamicMplCanvas(self.ac_graph,width = 10, height =3 , dpi = 60)
```

Basically, the last line of my code initialises the Canvas and draws my plot. But I'm looking to create several objects (plots) from this class and the problem is that I need to be able to change the title, axis labels of each individual plot.

I have tried defining a variable "title" in the **init** of MyDynamicMplCanvas, like so:

```
class MyDynamicMplCanvas(MyMplCanvas):

    def __init__(self, title, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        self.title = title

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        ...
        self.axes.set_title(self.title)
        ...

class Monitor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    ...
    self.ac_1_graph = MyDynamicMplCanvas('Title Here!', self.ac_graph,width = 10, height =3 , dpi = 60)
```

This causes the program to not load saying:
`RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MyDynamicMplCanvas was never called`

So I was wondering if anyone could give me some guidance on how I could create a class variable I could define for each different object

Comment: The title of the question in unclear. Please specify the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The init for MyDynamicMplCanvas class should call super:

```
def __init__(self, title, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyDynamicMp1Canvas, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.title = title
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm still getting the same error even with this super line.

Comment: Okay I got it to work when I define `self.title = title` before the super call. Can anybody explain why it has to be done before? Thanks!